# WooCommerce: overwrite product names on Cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to overwrite product names on WooCommerce Cart view with custom names.

What I've done so far:

`$cart_item_data = array(); $cart_item_data['product_name'] = 'Custom Product Name'; WC()->cart->add_to_cart ( $product_id, $qty, $variation_id, $all_variations, $cart_item_data);`

The 5th parameter should contain the custom product name and display them in the Cart, but nothing changes. Changing $qty to 4, for example, does change all cart product quantities to 4. So what is the correct parameter and the key to use here to overwrite product names?

Answer (score 0):

The `$cart_item_data` array is mainly used to store additional information about the cart item, but doesn't overwrite product name

To overwrite the product name in the cart, you need to use a `woocommerce_cart_item_name` filter

Example:

```
function custom_product_name_in_cart( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if ( $cart_item['product_id'] === YOUR_PRODUCT_ID ) {

        // Overwrite name
        $product_name = 'Custom Product Name';
    }
    return $product_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_product_name_in_cart', 10, 3 );
```